# Extremely difficult time installing and using .net sdk with Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am simply trying to download .net sdk so that I can work on my company's codebase, and use Visual Studio as my editor for it. I keep running into constant stupid issues.

I downloaded .net sdk version 3.1.417. I'm using this version because my team specifically stated they only use this version for some reason. At this time, the output of `dotnet --list-sdks` was only `3.1.417 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]` and version showed accordingly. I then downloaded Visual Studio 2019 but deliberately did not choose to download any .net related workloads. When I tried to open my codebase, I got constant VS errors telling me that there was some compatibility issue opening files. I then modified my install and downloaded the .net workload which installed version `5.0.406` of the sdk. With this, I stopped getting VS errors, however every time I run dotnet restore or dotnet build I get some other ridiculous error:

`C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.406\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(55,5): error MSB4186: Invalid static method invocation syntax: "[MSBuild]::GetTargetFrameworkVersion('$(TargetFramework)', 2)". Method '[MSBuild]::GetTargetFrameworkVersion' not found. Static method invocation should be of the form: $([FullTypeName]::Method())...`

Per what I read online, i tried repairing my VS install using the installer, and still got this issue. I have no clue what this is nor what the issue is. I dont know whether this is a .net issue, a VS issue or what. I've never used .net before and now I regret trying to use it because it's so annoying and convoluted. You have different versions for the CLI, the framework, the standard, the SDK, the runtime, and what Visual Studio uses.